# .NET nested repeater - Button click calls OnItemCreated eventhandler, not OnItemCommand

Tags: .net, nested, repeater, itemcommand

I have a project with a simple nested repeater. When i click the button, the OnItemCommand event is not called but the OnItemCreated is called (however, it does not call the Page_Load event handler). What am I misssing?

**MARKUP**

```
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>my row</td>
        <td>my description</td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMain" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptMain_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="rptMain_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#45abdc;">
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="ibtnDoSomething" runat="server" CommandArgument="SELECT" Text="Clicky" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblMainData" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>

        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptChild_ItemCreated">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color:#bcbbcb;">
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblChildData" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

   </table>
```

**CODEBEHIND**
    DataTable _childdata = new DataTable();
            DataTable _data = new DataTable();

```
        public void Page_Load()
        {

            _data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text"));
            _data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommandValue"));

            DataRow _row1 = _data.NewRow();
            _row1["Text"] = "Butch";
            _row1["CommandValue"] = "31";
            DataRow _row2 = _data.NewRow();
            _row2["Text"] = "Karl";
            _row2["CommandValue"] = "2";
            DataRow _row3 = _data.NewRow();
            _row3["Text"] = "Suzie";
            _row3["CommandValue"] = "8";
            DataRow _row4 = _data.NewRow();
            _row4["Text"] = "Kara";
            _row4["CommandValue"] = "31";

            _data.Rows.Add(_row1);
            _data.Rows.Add(_row2);
            _data.Rows.Add(_row3);
            _data.Rows.Add(_row4);




            _childdata.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text"));
            _childdata.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommandValue"));

            DataRow _crow1 = _childdata.NewRow();
            _crow1["Text"] = "Butch";
            _crow1["CommandValue"] = "Cupcakes";
            DataRow _crow2 = _childdata.NewRow();
            _crow2["Text"] = "Karl";
            _crow2["CommandValue"] = "Cheese";
            DataRow _crow3 = _childdata.NewRow();
            _crow3["Text"] = "Suzie";
            _crow3["CommandValue"] = "Pizaa";
            DataRow _crow4 = _childdata.NewRow();
            _crow4["Text"] = "Kara";
            _crow4["CommandValue"] = "Tofu";
            DataRow _crow5 = _childdata.NewRow();
            _crow5["Text"] = "Butch";
            _crow5["CommandValue"] = "Bacon";
            DataRow _crow6 = _childdata.NewRow();
            _crow6["Text"] = "Karl";
            _crow6["CommandValue"] = "Ham";

            _childdata.Rows.Add(_crow1);
            _childdata.Rows.Add(_crow2);
            _childdata.Rows.Add(_crow3);
            _childdata.Rows.Add(_crow4);
            _childdata.Rows.Add(_crow5);
            _childdata.Rows.Add(_crow6);

            rptMain.DataSource = _data;
            rptMain.DataBind();

        }

        public void rptMain_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

                LinkButton ibtn = e.Item.FindControl("ibtnDoSomething") as LinkButton;
                Label mainLabel = e.Item.FindControl("lblMainData") as Label;
                ibtn.CommandArgument = drv["CommandValue"].ToString();
                mainLabel.Text = drv["Text"].ToString();
                DataView _dv = new DataView(_childdata, "Text = '" + drv["Text"].ToString() + "'", "Text", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
                Repeater _rptChild = e.Item.FindControl("rptChild") as Repeater;
                _rptChild.DataSource = _dv;
                _rptChild.DataBind();
            }

        }

        public void rptChild_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                Label childLabel = e.Item.FindControl("lblChildData") as Label;
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
                childLabel.Text = drv["Text"].ToString();

            }
        }

        public void rptMain_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("fdasdfsa");
        }
```

Comment: I have investigated further and it doesnt even have to be a nested repeater. I removed the child repeater and the button click still calls the ItemCreated event handler. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeater is going to be re-created during a postback.  That's why the OnItemCreated event is firing.  The reason the OnItemCommand is not being called is because an exception is occurring in your OnItemCreated event.  The property

```
e.Item.DataItem
```

is not available in a postback and returns null.  So when you try to access it with

```
ibtn.CommandArgument = drv["CommandValue"].ToString();
```

you end up with a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I added a check for Postback in the Page_Load but it still breaks. I then added a check for Postback around the ItemCreated logic and it works. The wierd thing is, the lifecycle seems to go ItemCreated --> Page_Load --> ItemCommand. I cant think of any time that I have seen a Repeater control act like this, its usually Page_Load --> ItemCommand. Im not quite sure what is causing this.

Comment: Remember that your control must be recreated by asp.net at the beginning of the page lifecycle.  This occurs before Page_Load, so that's why you're seeing the ItemCreated event before the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to stop those nasty postback firings of Item_Created

```
protected void On_Item_Created(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify a CommandName attribute on your linkbutton control?

Comment: I did add it to be safe but I dont think its necessary for calling the ItemCommand event handler.